# How can I merge multiple variables together to create one variable?

Tags: r

I am analyzing data from a questionnaire, and for one of the questions, multiple answers were possible. Since multiple answers were possible, each answer choice is its own variable (2 of the variables are shown below, a 0 indicates 'no' and a 1 indicates 'yes')

```
                     Main income source_ex1                     Main income source_ex2
                                       0                                    0
                                       0                                    0
                                       0                                    0
                                       0                                    1
                                       0                                    0
```

I want to merge these two variables so that i can easily obtain a raw count and % for each source of income (example shown below).

```
   Income changed after 2020 (%)    
          Yes, I lost a total of income 62 (15.5)
          Yes, I lost a partial of income   307 (76.9)
          No, I earn the same amount of income  15 (3.8)
          Yes, I earn more income   15 (3.8)
```

So that it looks like

```
   Main income source N (%) 
          Ex. 1 N (%)
          Ex. 2 N (%)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your description is not particularly easy to follow. It seems that you may want simple column totals.

```
df<-data.frame(q1 = c(0,0,0,0,0), q2 = c(0,0,0,1,0))
colMeans(df)
colSums(df)
```